# How do I properly handle removal of a Blazor rendered element by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, blazor, web-component, blazor-webassembly

I know changing DOM by Javacript within a framework like Blazor is a bad idea but right now I cannot see any workaround. I have a list of custom components (Material Web `<MdInputChip>`) rendered by Blazor's `for` that iterates through an array. The chip could be removed by user by clicking an `X` button. When user clicks `X`, the Web Component code remove itself from the DOM (I cannot change this behavior).

Here's a reproducible code that simulates my situation:

```
<div @key="DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()">
    @for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        var z = i;
        var item = values[z];

        <p @key="@(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + z)" @onchange="(() => Remove(z))">
            @(item)
            <button onclick="this.parentElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); this.parentElement.remove();">
                Remove
            </button>
        </p>
    }
</div>



@code {

    List<string> values = new() { "A", "B", "C" };

    void Remove(int index)
    {
        values.RemoveAt(index);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", values));
    }

}
```

[image]

Problem is, when I click Remove on B for example, C also got removed **most of the time**. Then I tried adding `@key`, first to the `<p>` elements but it would cause all kind of weird problems when the array is modified further, then to the container `<div>` (and I also tried removing `@key` from `<p>`). I thought it fix it at first but turned out the problem gets **rarer** but it happens sometimes.

In my case, re-rendering that whole area is fine and performance is not critical. What are my options? Is there anyway to tell Blazor to just dispose that whole area and render everything new?

---

Just want to update that for my specific case, luckily the event can be cancelled with `preventDefault()` so I can do this:

```js
export function beforeStart() {
    document.addEventListener("remove", e => {
        if (e.target?.tagName === "MD-INPUT-CHIP") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }        
    });
}
```

Comment: Is `<MdInputChip>` a Blazor component?  At the moment [without more context] I can't see the point to the JS code.   What is almost certainly happening is that the click action triggers the first event handler on B button.  This removes the button.  The change event [a different event on the same action] then gets attributed to the element now under the cursor [button C].  So the JS script deletes one button and the Blazor event handler deletes the other.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis `<MdInputChip>` is a Blazor component but it renders a JS Web Component (printing out `<md-input-chip>`). The `<md-input-chip>` is written by Google and I cannot change the behavior. The JS code in my question is to demonstrate what the web component does (that I cannot change). `<p>` is the equivalent to `<md-input-chip>` in my real code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  This needs some thinking about, I will come back if I come up with anything constructive.